# SQL Query Modification/Optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to figure out how to make these 3 queries into one with a percentage column that i havent been able to figure out. Can anyone assist?

```
Select DISTINCT a.ASSN As Association, SUM(tonnage_adjusted) as TotalTonnage        
From DeliveryTons d INNER JOIN ReapingGroups a ON d.reaping_code = a.REAPING_GROUP_CODE
WHERE reaping_code IS NOT NULL 
Group By a.ASSN
ORDER BY Association


Select DISTINCT a.ASSN As Association, SUM(tonnage_adjusted) as Monitored       
From DeliveryTons d INNER JOIN ReapingGroups a ON d.reaping_code = a.REAPING_GROUP_CODE
WHERE remarks = '' AND reaping_code IS NOT NULL 
Group By a.ASSN
ORDER BY Association


Select DISTINCT a.ASSN As Association, SUM(tonnage_adjusted) as NotMonitored        
From DeliveryTons d INNER JOIN ReapingGroups a ON d.reaping_code = a.REAPING_GROUP_CODE
WHERE remarks = 'NO_TICKET' AND reaping_code IS NOT NULL 
Group By a.ASSN
ORDER BY Association
```

Comment: what's the formula for the percentage column? Also, what version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: It should be what is monitored divided by totaltonnage times 100. im using Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
With Summary as (
    Select a.ASSN As Association
          ,SUM(tonnage_adjusted) as TotalTonnage
          ,SUM(case when remarks = '' THEN tonnage_adjusted ELSE NULL END) as Monitored
          ,SUM(case when remarks = 'NO_TICKET' THEN tonnage_adjusted ELSE NULL END) as NotMonitored
    From DeliveryTons d 
    INNER JOIN ReapingGroups a 
    ON d.reaping_code = a.REAPING_GROUP_CODE
    WHERE d.reaping_code IS NOT NULL 
    Group By a.ASSN
    )

SELECT Association
      ,TotalTonnage
      ,Monitored
      ,NotMonitored
      ,((Monitored/TotalTonnage) * 100) as pct_Monitored
    FROM Summary
    Order by Association
```

Comment: Im getting a Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

Comment: Maybe the parenthesis? I edited, but I can't test so not sure what's causing it.

Comment: Getting invalid column name at the top for Association, TotalTonnage, Monitored etc as well as Invalid Syntax near 'Order' and Invalid column name for Association at the bottom

Comment: @ivias Maybe a SQL Server syntax issue I'm not aware of. Moved the inner query into a named subquery. Try to see if just the portion called Summary runs by itself.
Also removed the DISTINCT from select. Not needed since you're already grouping by ASSN.

Comment: @ivias There may also be an issue that there are no aliases on the tonnage_adjusted and remarks fields. I'm not sure whether they come from DeliveryTons or ReapingGroups, so I did not add them. It may not run until you do though.

Comment: Okay i got results. Will check it out. Thanks very much for your help

Comment: @ivias Great! Please accept my answer if it works for you.